# Iframe-resizer implementation in angualr 10 (dynamically added iframe using loader.js)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive, iframe-resizer

I am trying to use iframe-resizer in angualr 10 for cross domain sites where the iframe is getting added by loader.js using create element and setting dynamic src, till here everthig is working fine but as per angular implementation we need to add the directive and add selector to iframe tag but here we are adding that tag using loader file  not hardcoded so how could I add that directive in case of dynamically created iframe tags, or is there any other way to implement it.

Thanks